# How to implement facebook ads in Android studio

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-ads

How to implement facebook ads in Android studio
I want to know how to add Facebook ads from scratch, as I have no experience

I couldn't find an easy way to explain this
I want a video explaining this in an easy way, or an explanation with pictures, or even written steps. The most important thing is that it be in a very simplified way so that I can apply the method correctly.